Can't import dynamic from "libvmod-dynamic" in v7.3.0
Using varnish 7.3, trying to do 'import dynamic from libvmod-dynamic, but get error
"Could not find VMOD dynamic"

Am I doing this wrong or is it not include in 7.3?
If not, any tips to install it? I am upgrading from 5.0
What I am doing wrong as It fails to import although,  I am guessing it's not included in the package.
Here is my code below:
import dynamic from "libvmod-dynamic";

dynamic.set("ipAddressCookie", "");

dynamic.set("ipAddressCookie", regsub(req.http.Cookie, "^.*ipAddress=(.*?);(.*)$", "\1"));


If you're using the official Varnish Docker images, the VMOD should be in /usr/lib/varnish/vmods folder as libvmod_dynamic.so.
If you installed Varnish via a package manager, I suggest you take a look at https://github.com/nigoroll/libvmod-dynamic/tree/7.3 for installation instructions.
Apparently Uplex offers packages for this VMOD through https://pkg.uplex.de/.
